# Execute a python function on a server

Tags: python, pythonanywhere

it's my first question here so i'll try to be clear :)

I want to execute a python script on a server (I use [pythonanywhere](https://www.pythonanywhere.com)), this script is took from [spawningtool](https://github.com/StoicLoofah/spawningtool). I succeed on the install and I'm able do execute it in a shell on the user interface.

The problem is that I want to execute it when a client ask ^^, here a classic situation :

1. The client send a file to the server
2. The server execute the script with the file in parameter
3. The server answer with a string

How can I do that ? (Does it have a link with Django,Bottle etc . . . ?)

PS : Python stuff is new for me so take in consideration that I'm a mobile dev with very few notion of python and web dev.

Comment: This all depends on how the client is sending the file to the server. If it's a web interface you'll probably want some form of server side script (python-django, php, perl) that will do what you want by running the script with the file as a parameter. If it's via like FTP/SFTP then that becomes a whole new problem in itself.

Comment: I'll probably use the "easiest" way for the first shoot, with the form in the server side.

Comment: SO is not a place to post questions like "Teach me all about web development". Go read some docs, write some code, come back with a concrete question when you get stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're definitely going to have to learn a lot about web development to make that happen. Have a look at tutorials for Django, Flask or Bottle. Get an idea of how the web works and then apply it to your problem.

Comment: +1 to using Bottle or Flask for this particular use case.  Django is awesome, but for just remotely executing an existing script it's probably too heavyweight.